# For the Raulothim's Psychic Lance spell, do only true names work, or do pseudonyms work too?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

I think the rules for [*Raulothim's psychic lance*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/raulothims-psychic-lance) are pretty vague. The spell description states (FToD, p. 21):

> You unleash a shimmering lance of psychic power from your forehead at a creature that you can see within range. **Alternatively, you can utter a creature's name.** If the named target is within range, it becomes the spell's target even if you can't see it. If the named target isn't within range, the lance dissipates without effect.

**Do you have to utter the creature's true name specifically? Or do pseudonyms work too?**

As an example, the [*summon greater demon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-greater-demon) spell (XGtE, p. 166) clearly specifies "say its true name" - while in this spell, it only says "utter a creature's name", so it could also mean "I know this person by this name, even if it's a pseudonym".

Also, I think it might be a little overpowered to be able to hit even if you don't know the creature's true name.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I think your question as it stands is more of an opinion than something that could get a definitive answer, which is kinda a requirement of these forums.  You could possibly rephrase to ask how this spell compares in power to other spells of the same level? (Also your question implies that you think knowing a creatures name makes it auto-hit? Which isn't the case: it merely allows you to choose that creature as a target if it's within range)

Comment: This may be relevant, or maybe not: the Unearthed Arcana with the Onomancer wizard has a sidebar on true names, though that is "true names" as opposed to "names". https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-TwilightFireNames.pdf

Comment: @Phoenices I didn't know of its existence, but it sounds pretty interesting. Mechanics like this could incentivize roleplay and thinking out of the box while still having precise rules. It would have been an interesting addition to a manual like Fizban's...

Comment: If you try it, try to get an allowance from your DM to be able to retry somehow if it doesn't work the first time. My DM said "if you do research on the target, you can retry," basically. If you can find someone's name by asking them, that works too.
I would approve of adding it, but some people would say "This has nothing to do with dragons! Why did Fizban include it in his treasury?" Or maybe they'd fluff it as some kind of Raulothim-follower. Of course, they did include a psionic bolt and claim it was Raulothim-themed, so maybe it's not out of the question. A Raulothim wizard would be fun.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Either option works

The guiding principles you should use when interpreting the rules for spells are:

1. Spells only do what they say they do
2. D&D 5e uses the natural language meaning of language if it's not a defined game term
3. Specific beats general

For this specific spell, the description of [*Raulothim's psychic lance*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/raulothims-psychic-lance) states, that as an alternative targeting option :

> [...] you can utter a creature's name. If the creature is within range, it becomes the spell’s target even if you can’t see it. [...]

So, for this spell, the utterance of a name is a special rule for targeting that overrides the general spell targeting rules (namely that if you know a creatures name and they are in range you can target them specifically if they are in range). As the spell doesn't state "true name" we cannot *assume* any such restriction on the targeting.

Thus we fall back on the natural language meaning of a creature's name (some set of words or sounds that a creature of thing is known, addressed or referred to). Importantly, a name should uniquely identify a creature or thing.

For example, if you wanted to target a white dragon called Toby, King of The North (true name: Jolzoriat) in your campaign, a user of this spell could target them using one of two - four names (depending on how permissive your DM is):

1. Toby
2. Jolzoriat
3. King of the North
4. Toby, King of the North

What you cannot do is try to target "the white dragon" if you cannot see it.

Now, once a creature has become a target, the next paragraph of the spell description says:

> The target must make an Intelligence saving throw.

This saving throw determines how much the target of the spell (either seen or named) is affected by the spell (assuming they are in range). But either way, there is no *attack* roll.

As to whether or not the spell is overpowered as a result of this (slight) modification to the targeting rules...no. The targeting only applies in very specific edge cases:

1. where you *know* one of the names that a specific creature is known by

   - noting a specific creature's species/type/description are not its "name" under the natural language interpretation
2. You are fighting them or intend to harm them
3. They are hidden from you in some way

Comment: I love the concept of naming a supremely powerful white dragon Toby.

Comment: Interesting...if you asked the (maybe white dragon wouldn't think of this...say its a green) dragon its name, and it lied and say "Jeff"...would "Jeff" work? If there is a henchman of the dragon named Jeff, and the dragon lies and says its name is Jeff...who gets targeted?

Comment: so the idea of a 'name' has no official guidance? It is up to DM's decision?

Comment: @ArtickokeAndAnchovyPizzaMonica the idea of name within the game is the same as the idea of name within our world. Whether or not something is a name in English (or another language), or not, is something that inherently requires a judgement call, and thus requires adjudication by the DM.

Comment: @sharur if I'm the DM and the dragon has identified itself to the players as "Jeff", then for the purposes of the interaction with the players the dragon has the name Jeff and thus the player would correctly target the dragon using Jeff. A name is a way for creatures to identify each other, so absent any other information, the name the creature calls itself in its interactions with you is it's name from your perspective. Similarly, if a creature is famous enough to have a moniker (think Beyoncé or Madonna) then that moniker is *also* their name. A title that can only be held by one creature...

Comment: ...at a time, for example King Under The Mountain, then that title would also satisfy the criteria of their name. However something like "Masked Lord of Waterdeep" which is a title bestowed to many creatures, would not serve the function of a name.

Comment: @Zweiclops1206 Glad to have improved your day. :)

Comment: @illustro: Fair enough; I'm just thinking of a "Nemo" scenario (from the Oddessy), I guess...

Comment: @sharur if someone calls themselves "Nobody" (see the Faceless Man in Game of Thrones), a word that has a clear other meaning associated (to all parties) with a group of people (or lack thereof) then that's an edge case that would need DM adjudication. If they instead called themselves Nemo when speaking to a person who doesn't speak Greek, then to that person their name is Nemo (see Finding Nemo, or Captain Nemo) and would function as a name for the purposes of the spell. Its an interesting edge case :)